# Get dynamic test description in allure-pytest

Tags: python, pytest, allure

in pytest-allure is there a way to get the current test description after I set it with

```
allure.dynamic.description("""blah blah""")
```

Looking for something like:

```
description = pytest.xxx or request.node.xxx ....
```

I'm trying to explain better what I need. Every test calls a function before closing and it needs to know the value of testdescription. I do not want to save it in a variable and pass to the function. I would get it through allure variable.

```
@allure.title("MYTITLE")
def test_A1(self):
    allure.dynamic.description("""MYDESC""")
    ...
    myfunct()


def myfunct():
    testdescription = ???
    ...
    message: "Test done " + testdescription  
    smtpObj.sendmail(sender, receivers, message)
```

Comment: Can you share a test example with setting the description? I'm not sure where to put the code line.

Comment: Could you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking into `allure_pytest` plugin sources, you can grab the correct plugin object from the plugin manager that stores the infos:

```python
import allure
from allure_commons._core import plugin_manager
from allure_pytest.listener import AllureListener


@allure.title("MYTITLE")
def test_A1(request):
    allure.dynamic.description("""MYDESC""")
    myfunct()


def myfunct():
    plugin = next(p for p in plugin_manager.get_plugins() if isinstance(p, AllureListener))
    testdescription = plugin.allure_logger.get_test(None).description
    ...
```

However, beware that the API is not public (and it looks like it's not intended to be public), so watch out for changes in the implementation of `AllureListener` which can easily break `myfunct`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: Glad I could help!